# SpringBoot + Jackson + Kotlin data class : Field annotations ignored

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, kotlin

I'm using Spring Boot with Kotlin and Java8 time. Somehow the Jackson annotations on the data class fields are ignored.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import java.time.MonthDay

data class DataView(val id: String,
                    @get:JsonProperty("dayOfMonth") val monthDay: MonthDay) {}
```

Why would these annotations be ignored? The response still contains the field name "monthDay".

I know the annotation is correct, according to this discussion on [discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/difference-in-serialization-of-data-class-fields/3802).

I don't have any configurations that should affect this, as far as I know.

pom contains:

```
...
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
```

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain why they feel this is not a good question?

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I check this code local, and all looks fine

```
data class DataView(val id: String,
                     @get:JsonProperty("dayOfMonth") val monthDay: MonthDay)

data class MonthDay(val day: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
            .registerKotlinModule()

    val dataView = DataView("someId", MonthDay(1))

    //{"id":"someId","dayOfMonth":{"day":1}}
    println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataView))
}
```

It works same even if I remove `registerKotlinModule` and change from `@get` to `@field`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. In my case I'm using java.time.MonthDay, but I think it might have something to do with spring boot and the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

Comment: You could try to exclude all jackson-datatype* modules from project and check m.b it will help. As you see in empty project all works fine, so problem in ObjectMapper which has been configured in Spring.